# Align an image in the center of a td

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML structure, and I need to align the image (icon) vertically in the center of the td. I tried several options but no-one worked for me. Can you guys help? Thanks a lot.

```js
var row = $("<tr>" +
  "<td style='word-wrap:break-word; height:1px; padding-right:0; '>" +
  "<div style='float:left;width: 20%; height:100%;'>" +
  < i class = 'fa fa-cogs'
  style = 'font-size:14px;color:darkblue'
  data - toggle = 'tooltip'
  title = '100% Automatic' > < /i> +
  "</div>" +
  "<div style='float: right; width: 80%; height:100%;'>" +
  "<a style='width: 100%; text-decoration: underline;' href='" + url_target + "' target='_blank'>" +
  obj.HITO +
  "</div>" +
  "</td>" +
  "<td style='word-wrap:break-word'>" +
  "<a style='text-decoration: underline; color:" + colorPriority + "' href='" + url_proyect + "' target='_blank'>" +
  obj.NAME_PROYECT + "</td>" +
  "<td style='word-wrap:break-word'>" + obj.SUBDOMAIN + "</td>" +
  "<td style='word-wrap:break-word'>" + obj.TITLE + "</td>" +
  "<td style='word-wrap:break-word'>" + obj.NOTE + "</td>" +
  "<td style='word-wrap:break-word'>" + obj.MODIFIED + "</td>" +
  "<td style='word-wrap:break-word'>" + obj.RESPONSABLE + "</td>" +
  "<td style='word-wrap:break-word'>" + obj.PLANNED_DATE + "</td>" +
  "<td style='word-wrap:break-word'>" + obj.STATE + "</td>" +
  "<td style='word-wrap:break-word; background-color:" + colorSla + "'>" + obj.SLA + "</td></tr>");
}
$("#tableResult").children('tbody').append(row);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Added
 `style='word-wrap:break-word; vertical-align: middle' to the <td> tag, removed parent div from the <a> and the <i> and added <div style='height:100%; display: flex; align-items:center; margin: 0 auto;'> as the parent of both<a> and <i>`

Answer (score 2):

add style `vertical-align: middle`  to `td` holding the image icon and remove the parent `div` inside the `td`

```
<td style='word-wrap:break-word; height:1px; padding-right:0; vertical-align:middle '>
<i class='fa fa-cogs' data-toggle='tooltip' title='100% Automatic'></i>
<a href='url_target'>obj.HITO</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
td {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

If you set a `width` in the `td` (or the icon) add `margin: 0 auto;`